# How do I display geom_bar labels with values of thousands to "K" instead of the full numbers?

Tags: r, data-visualization, bar-chart, geom-bar

So I figured out how to display thousands with "K" for the y-axis with the `scale_y_continuous()` function but I don't know how I could go about doing the same for each of my labels.

```
ggplot(ctd_num_rides,
       aes(x=factor(day_of_week,level=
                      c('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
                        'Thursday', 'Friday','Saturday',
                        'Sunday')),
           y=number_of_rides,
           fill=member_casual)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',width=.65,position='dodge') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number(suffix = " K", scale = 1e-3)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=number_of_rides),
  position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
  labs(title='Number of Rides by Each User Type & Day of Week',
       fill='User Type') +
  xlab('Day of Week') +
  ylab('Number of Rides')
```

The above code returns the following visual:

[image]

As you can see, the numbers for each labels show the entire raw numbers but I want it to be round up to the nearest thousand and show 446K instead of 445635, as an example.

Also, is it possible to add lines connecting each of the bars to show the differences visually? This is what I'm imagining but don't really know how to put it into words:

[image]

```
> dput(ctd_num_rides)
structure(list(member_casual = c("casual", "casual", "casual", 
"casual", "casual", "casual", "casual", "member", "member", "member", 
"member", "member", "member", "member"), day_of_week = c("Friday", 
"Monday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Friday", "Monday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday"), number_of_rides = c(358203L, 289029L, 558617L, 
477032L, 298061L, 270548L, 284868L, 453281L, 445635L, 442741L, 
388042L, 485843L, 498682L, 506969L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), groups = structure(list(
    member_casual = c("casual", "member"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:7, 8:14), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Could you share your `ctd_num_rides` using `dput(ctd_num_rides)` to reproduce your expected output?

Comment: @YHJang I added the result to the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`label_number` returns a function:

```
library(scales)
label_number(scale=1e-3, suffix='K')(123456.789)
## 123K
label_number(scale=1e-3, suffix='K')(123567.890)
## 124K
```

so you should be able to use:

```
geom_text(aes(label=label_number(scale=1e-3, suffix='K')(number_of_rides)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Was a bit confused as to where I can insert the `position=` after that but I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

For the lines you can add

```
+ stat_summary(aes(group = member_casual, color = member_casual),
fun = "identity", geom = "line")
```

Comment: This works well! Sorry but I couldn't make two posts an answer.